# Intellij javascript method comments

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, comments

Is there a way to configure the template that is used to generate javascript documentation on methods? I couldn't seem to find a way to access it for javascript (seems like you can for some other languages).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the Settings section, then 'File Templates' click "Javascript" then edit template to the right.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-templates.html